# How to push to an anonymous 3 element array referenced in a hash

Tags: perl

I am trying to "push" onto an anonymous 3 element array whose reference is stored in a hash:

```
my %messages;
my $to = "To";
... later ...
$messages{$msg_id}{$to} = [ [], [], [] ];
```

which basically works, because Data::Dumper shows an empty 3 element array.
My problem is I can't work out how to "push" data onto this anonymous array!

I have tried many things, but realise I am just thrashing about. A couple of examples of my many failures!

```
my word = "something";
push(@{ $messages{$msg_id}{$to} }->[0], ( $word ));
Can't use an array as a reference at ./hash_array.pl line 53.
```

```
my @array = ( word1, word2, word3 );
push(\@{ $messages{$msg_id}{$to} }, ( @array ));
Experimental push on scalar is now forbidden at ./hash_array.pl line 54, near "))"
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to "create" an empty array before pushing to it. Perl's autovivification will do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to move the `->[0]` into `@{...}`.
The first argument of `push` must be an array, not a reference.
See also: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %messages;
my $msg_id = 123;
my $to = "To";
$messages{$msg_id}{$to} = [ [], [], [] ];

my $word = "something";
push(@{ $messages{$msg_id}{$to}->[0] }, ( $word ));

print Dumper \%messages;

1;
```

Comment: Note that the second arrow (`->`) can be omitted just like the first. `$messages{$msg_id}->{$to}->[0]` is equivalent to `$messages{$msg_id}{$to}[0]`

Comment: Also, since v5.20 (stable from v5.24) can `push $messages{$msg_id}{$to}[0]->@*, $word;`.  This is [postfix dereferencing](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Postfix-Dereference-Syntax).